# Enable multiple webroot for apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web-hosting, digital-ocean

I'm using *apache2* on my *ubuntu 13.10* machine, I have added another config file named *paul* under */etc/apache2/sites-available* directory to make my file under */home/paul/public_html/* accessible on internet:

```
root@localhost:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  950 Feb  7  2012 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  978 Jun 23 10:54 paul
```

After than changes, my files under */var/www* is not accessible on URL anymore, unless I change DocumentRoot from /*home/paul/public_html* to */var/www* , but that would disable accessibility for /home/paul/public_html/

/etc/apache2/sites-available/paul :

```
    DocumentRoot /home/paul/public_html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
```

Is there any way of configuration to enable */var/www* and */home/paul/pubilc_html* as webroot at the same time? Is it required any setting on */etc/apache2/apache2.conf* ? Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So you want `http://www.example.com/` to show `/var/www` and `http://paul/` to show your `public_html`?

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, two different url to access my pages under two different folders.

Comment: Definitely possible. Two different URLs or two different domains?

Comment: @andrewsomething Two different URLs under same domain is good enough for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily with an [alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html). In  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` just add an `Alias` for the URL.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        Alias /paul /home/paul/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the contents of `/home/paul/public_html` should be available at www.example.com/paul